# Why can't I install Pipelight on my Samsung Chromebook

Tags: ppa, pipelight

When I follow the commands to get Pipelight on my Chromebook it gets through the first 2 steps: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable` and `sudo apt-get update`. But when I get to the 3th step I get this:

> E: Unable to locate package pipelight

The outputs of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -m` are as follows:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 
Release: 14.04 
Codename: trusty 

armv7l
```

Comment: May be it's not available for your OS, and may be for the hardware architecture. To verify, add the outputs of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -m` to the question.

Comment: @mikewhatever This is what i get  No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty                                           armv7l

Comment: Well, armv7l hardware architecture is your problem. The packages available in the PPA are i386 and amd64 only. You have an ARM-based machine, and not an Intel/AMD.

Comment: @mikewhatever so ur saying i wont beable to get it cause i dont have the right architecture is thier anyway i can get those architectures?

Comment: Yep, that is what I am saying, and no, you can't change the hardware architecture, sorry. By the way, if it's about Netflix, it does work without silverlight: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/psa-netflix-ubuntu-now-working-box.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Chromebook has an ARM CPU. This CPU is similar to that of a smartphone or tablet and is very different from those made by Intel or AMD. The circuits around the CPU are also very different. That's called a different hardware architecture.

To change the hardware architecture you have to get a new Chromebook with Intel architecture.

The programs written for Intel will not work in ARM architecture. The pipelight is one such program.

Hope this helps